# Kafka streams API not reading input topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on Kafka streams application but it's giving the following error when I run:-
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, PropertyInit())

```
org.apache.Kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:729)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:653)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:563)
at AC.kafka.StreamManagersms.start(StreamManagersms.java:80)
at AC.kafka.App.main(App.java:30)
```

This is my code

```
public void start(){
    try {
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        List<String> topicList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] inputtopiclist = CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs()
                .get_input_topic()
                .split(",");
        for (String string : inputtopiclist) {

            topicList.add(string);  
        }
        final Serde<GenericRecord> keyserdes = genericserdescreator();
        final Serde<GenericRecord> valueserdes = genericserdescreator();
        final KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> Streamsms = builder.stream(topicList, Consumed.with(keyserdes, valueserdes));
        builder.addStateStore(getstore());

        Streamsms.transform(suppliermechanisem(), CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs().GET_UNIQUE_STORE_NAME());

        Topology topology = builder.build();
        TopologyDescription description = topology.describe();
        System.out.println(description);

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, PropertyInit());//building topology
        streams.start();//start Kafka threads
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is propertyInit:

```
    private Properties PropertyInit() {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,
            CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs().get_UNIQUE_APPLICATION_ID());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs().get_bootstrapservers());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
    props.put("schema.registry.url",
            CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs().get_ConsumerschemaRegistry());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
            CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs().get_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG,
            CacheContainer.GetApplicationconfigs().get_NO_OF_THREADS());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    return props;
}
```

The following gets printed when I print the topology description

```
 Topologies:
 Sub-topology: 0
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [bulk, 
transaction, promotion])
   --> KSTREAM-TRANSFORM-0000000001
  Processor: KSTREAM-TRANSFORM-0000000001 (stores: [communication])
   --> none
    <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
```

the topology clearly shows the input topics then why does it say no stream threads?
how do i solve this ??

Comment: You have no output for the transform

Comment: doesn't matter, I did add one but still got the same result

Comment: @Akash did you found a solution to your issue?